# App supports only LIGHT MODE but status bar not consistent when device goes to dark mode

Tags: ios, react-native, statusbar

Everything working fine on LIGHT MODE
But when device goes to dark mode status bar suddenly change to `UIStatusBarStyleLightContent` but need is always stay for `UIStatusBarStyleDarkContent`
this issue only happen when app comes from to background to foreground.

did all the setting and apply code on applicationDidEnterBackground and applicationDidBecomeActive as well but not working.

Code written in both REACT NATIVE and objetive-C

kindly reply if any one have i idea what could be issue

Answer (score 0):

This is the issue with iOS 15 where:
Launch screen in an initial scene to decide the global property like status bar what to be on next of screens if you don't have any setting inside the app

Step to resolve the issue

1. Set the status bar style to `Dark Content` in info.plist
2. Delete the existing `Launch Screen` and create a fresh `Launch Screen` with your requirement
3. Set the newly created `Launch Screen` into `Launch Screen File` inside general section

clean the app and build is ... issue has been resolved now either app is running on `DARK MODE` or `LIGHT MODE`